# JAXRS-2.0 Filter: How does one add links to ContainerResponse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, apache-tomee, hypermedia

I'm implementing a `ContainerResponseFilter` that would add hypermedia links to the response.

The method signature in the `ContainerResponseFilter` is:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
```

Unfortunately `ContainerResponseContext` does not allow me to set a `Response` object, and while there are `getLinks()` methods, there are not `addLink(Link)` or `setLinks(Link...)` methods.

I tried

```
responseContext.setEntity(Response.ok().links(link).build());
```

but that resulted in an exception that said they could find a `MessageBodyWriter` for `ResponseImpl`. Also tried

```
responseContext.getLinks().add(link);
```

which doesn not work either.

Anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 0):

You should inject:

```
@Context HttpServletResponse r;
```

as a local field. All changes should be done through there.

Comment: :/ I don't want to manipulate the response directly... I'll link marshalling/encoding and stuff to happen

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to do this, by replacing the entity:

```
URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(RESOURCE_CLASS).path(RESOURCE_METHOD).build(domain_object.getId());
JaxbLink jaxbLink = new JaxbLink(uri);
responseContext.setEntity(jaxbLink);
```

Not certain this is a 100% correct, but it seems to work.